# Adding custom fields on user with Jhipster and okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta

I'm trying to add a custom field on User in Jhipster and Okta.

The problem is that I'm not getting it along all the other fields in `UserService`:

```
    public UserDTO getUserFromAuthentication(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        ...
        Map<String, Object> details = (Map<String, Object>) authentication.getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
        ...
    }
```

In Okta, I configured them both on the regular `User` and also on the `<myapp> User`, but when I preview the mappings, I see that the `Okta to <myapp>` mappings work fine, but `<myapp> to Okta` leaves my field with `null`.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The OIDC support in JHipster has a feature where the user's data is pulled in from the IdP (Okta in this case) and saved in the JHipster database. There is no UI that allows you to modify the `User` object, nor is there any code that syncs the data in the local user to the IdP. It's meant to be read-only.

Comment: I saw that, that's why I'm trying to add the data to okta, so that it will be modified there.

Comment: What do you mean by `<myapp> to Okta`? My guess is you're trying to write data from your app back to Okta.

Comment: What I'm referring to is that in Okta if you go to `Users` -> `Profile Editor` you see 2 profiles (1 named `User` and the other `<myapp> User`).
You can edit both profiles, and also the mappings.
I added my field on bot profiles, and also mapped it back and forth between both.
In the mapping editor you can map: `Okta to <myapp>` and also `<myapp> to Okta`.
That's what I am referring to.

Comment: essentially - I'm trying to add a custom field, have it defined in Okta, and available on my Jhipster user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - after adding the fields you want to the profile, you have to also add them to the claims: `API` -> `Authorization Servers` -> `edit` -> `Claims`.

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out! We should update the JHipster docs to have this information.